# scanimage, left and top padding when using selection, fine if whole page

Tags: linux, scanning, sane

I have this troubleshoot when scanning with my HP Photosmart 5520 using scanimage (same problem with xsane though) :

If I scan with no selection area, then it's fine, I get everything.
But when I set an area (via -x -y for example), there are 5 to 7 millimeter missing at the left and the top, and I can't figure out why ( I also tried to pass -l 0 and -t 0 but no changes)
...It's kind of boring having to wait the whole scan while I just need a specific area...

Any ideas ?